# How to get an element data after parseJSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, parsing

When I echo a variable, where the variable contains the data fetched from database.

```
    $query = "Select cal_date, mfg_name, sales_amt, mkt_share 
              from (---here comes subquery--) 
              group by TO_DATE(cal_date, 'YYYYMMDD'), mfg_name 
              order by mfg_name, cal_date


    $data = json_encode($results);
    echo $data; die();
```

The output resulted as below.

```
    {"8":{
          "CAL_DATE":"01-APR-2013",
          "MFG_NAME":"AMS",
          "SALES_AMT":"1630",
          "MKT_SHARE":".01"
         },
     "9":{
          "CAL_DATE":"01-AUG-2012",
          "MFG_NAME":"TEVA",
          "SALES_AMT_USD":"876",
          "MKT_SHARE":".59"
         }
     }
```

I don't know why I am getting the "8" "9" before each element data. How do I get the MFG_NAME from this in alert. Like I have tried the below

```
var cdata = new Array();
cdata = <?php echo $data; ?>; 
var dlen    = cdata.length;
var mfg_name    = new Array();

for(var i=0 ; i<dlen; i++ )
{
    mfg_name[i]   = cdata[i].MFG_NAME;
}
alert(mfg_name);
```

I got empty result in alert. For example, how do I get `AMS, TEVA` in my alert above? Do I have to do parseJSON or how to I get it?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Put all the relevant code in your question please. Then you might get HELP and not GUESSES.

Comment: This is what my relevant code. I have kept most of the code that is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
cdata = '{"8":{"CAL_DATE":"01-APR-2013","MFG_NAME":"AMS","SALES_AMT":"1630","MKT_SHARE":".01"},"9":{"CAL_DATE":"01-AUG-2012","MFG_NAME":"TEVA","SALES_AMT_USD":"876","MKT_SHARE":".59"}}';
cdata = JSON.parse(cdata);
var mfg_name    = new Array();
var i = 0;
for(var key in cdata ){
   mfg_name[i]  = cdata[key].MFG_NAME;
   i++;
}
alert(mfg_name);
```

Alerts `AMS,TEVA`

Answer (score 0):

So, your PHP is ouputting a JSON string since there is no content type header set. Therefore, you need to parse it as JSON object and then loop thru the keys to access the values, like below.

```
var json = JSON.parse('{"8":{"CAL_DATE":"01-APR-2013","MFG_NAME":"AMS","SALES_AMT":"1630","MKT_SHARE":".01"},"9":{"CAL_DATE":"01-AUG-2012","MFG_NAME":"TEVA","SALES_AMT_USD":"876","MKT_SHARE":".59"}}');

for (var key in json) {
    alert (json[key]["MFG_NAME"]);
}
```

Demo@[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/fe01e5sa/3/)